# storekit framework not working in ios simulator 5.1

Tags: ios, dyld

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController
  Referenced from: /Users/fazal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/CCA58B68-1765-4697-BCC9-8EC251CADC66/Motorcycle Race Track Free.app/Motorcycle Race Track Free
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
```

Answer (score 3):

[SKStoreProductViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html)

**Availability**
Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem as your previous question. The StoreKit framework is only available from iOS 6.0 and later.